# Yup field validation schema with name containing special character

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I am using Yup for validation schema with Formik.
The form field name contains a period(.) special character.
It needs to contains this special character as this name is referenced by the action.
The field name is like "traits.name.first".
I defined the validation schema as

```
yup.object().shape({
"traits.name.first": yup.string().required("Please enter the first name"))};
```

but the validation is not working.
Is this supported and valid with Yup using the field name as `"traits.name.first"`?
Please let me know how to make it work.
Currently this validation is not working and ignored.

Comment: I think you need to rename your form fields.  Because using a dot within the name of a JSON object property is not going to go very well, and the `Yup.object().shape({})` is a json object with keys (object property names), and their values which are functions (validation rules).

Comment: Unfortunately the naming is defined in the action in the server. The data binding at the backend using this name.

Comment: can you share how your component looks like ? . How are you passing the initial value ? . It will be easier to help .

Answer (score 0):

Please re-define your state structure to have Array of Objects. So that you can have an own yup schema for the nested Object.

Example

```
const initialValues={
         social: {
           facebook: '',
           twitter: '',
         }
       }
const schema = yup.object().shape({
     social: yup.object().shape({
           facebook: yup.string().required(),
           social: yup.string().required()
       })
})
```